# Memory error on linux server while fetching data from bigquery using python?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am trying to fetch data from big query using python. The code runs fine on my laptop but throws memory error on Linux server. Can this be optimized so that it can run on the server as well?

Error : table has 5 million rows...Linux machine with 8 GB ram....error "out of memory", process killed

Below is the code:

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/Users/Desktop/big_query_test/soy-serenity-89ed73.json"

client = bigquery.Client()

# Perform a query.

QUERY = “SELECT * FROM `soy-serenity-89ed73.events10`”


query_job = client.query(QUERY)

df = query_job.to_dataframe()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two approaches:

**option 1**
`SELECT` the data in chunks to reduce the size of the data you received on each iteration from BigQuery.
For example, your table is partition you can do this:

```
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = currentLoopDate
```

where currentLoopDate will be a date variable in your python code (Similar option will be to use `ROW_NUMBER`

**option 2**
By using [BigQuery client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) you can use a **Jobs.insert** API and set `configuration.query.priority` to batch.

```
# from google.cloud import bigquery
# client = bigquery.Client()

query = (
    'SELECT name FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013` '
    'WHERE state = "TX" '
    'LIMIT 100')
query_job = client.query(
    query,
    # Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
    location='US')  # API request - starts the query

for row in query_job:  # API request - fetches results
    # Row values can be accessed by field name or index
    assert row[0] == row.name == row['name']
    print(row)
```

See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries) for some more details
After you get the jobId write a loop using [Jobs.getQueryResults](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults) to get the chunks of data by setting the `maxResults` parameter of the API

Comment: @nk23 if my answer was helpful in any way will appreciate if you can accept/vote-up it, stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers –